# How to stretch UIView when swipe

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swipe

How can I stretch view when swipe out, like this:

[image: http://gifmaker.store/gifs/uploads/free/23-10-2017/1508772342.gif]

Image Link: http://gifmaker.store/gifs/uploads/free/23-10-2017/1508772342.gif

When user swipe down, the view stretch and the view come back to normal when release finger

Comment: This does not seem to be swipe gesture. It looks like Pan gesture. Implement pan gesture recognizer and track y-offset from start. Then with usage of constraints adjust view size. Try it and if you will be stuck somewhere, update question with your code.

Comment: Final, I used transform with some calculate for scale ratio
var scale: CGFloat = (startBackgroundFrame.width - touchXOffset)/startBackgroundFrame.width
        scale = 1 + scale*6/100 - 6/100
        backgroundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale < 1 ? 2-scale : scale, y: scale < 1 ? scale : 2 - scale )